# AWS congnito user pool attributes update

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have an AWS Cognito user pool enabled with a PreSignup lambda trigger. For some reason, I need to remove the trigger using `aws cognito-idp cli`. I am aware with the below command we can set new/update a lambda function ARN, but how can I set to none or delete the existing one. With the new and old AWS console, I can easily manage such action but the requirement is to do it through AWS CLI

`aws cognito-idp update-user-pool --user-pool-id=eu-west-1_xxXXXxxyy --lambda-config PreSignUp="<lambda-function-arn>:<function_name>:<function_alias>" --region eu-west-1`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use this command, I tested in my lab and it works (replace "YOUR_USER_POOL_ID" with your user pool ID):

```
aws cognito-idp update-user-pool --user-pool-id YOUR_USER_POOL_ID --lambda-config {}
```